# Problem to get Data with CURL from an API "*.glitch.me" Domain

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the JSON data from a Website called
"https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/"

It has some sort of protection and take a while to open.

The Problem. After the site is loaded, you get access to some API calls like

"https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes"

If I try it in Postman, I get back the right JSON response also if I open it up in the browser.

But if I try the to load the Data via curl in PHP i get the html code back from the first protection side. What can I do to get the JSON like in Postman.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes?count=1';
            
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));
            
$response = curl_exec($curl);
            
curl_close($curl);
```

thx for any help

Comment: When screen scraping, every server is different. Generally speaking, when it “works using XYZ but doesn’t work using ABC”, you need to mimic XYZ. That includes headers such as User Agent, and even header order sometimes. You might also be on a network that is considered hostile (or not friendly) by the server, so you might need to proxy.

Comment: "User Agent" was missing now it works thx